# Is it possible that absolute magnitude for two stars is equal for some wavelength?

Tags: star, absolute-magnitude

The title explains the questions. I don't find any problem with it. As If the two stars A and B do have equal absolute magnitude for some wavelength $\lambda_0$ then
$$M_A=M_B$$
$$-5(\log d_A-1)+m_A=-5(\log d_B-1)+m_B$$
$$m_A-m_B=5\log\left(\frac{d_A}{d_B}\right)$$
I don't find any problem with this. But I'm not sure if this is true. Can any help me with this?

Comment: This is like asking "Is it possible that two people have the same height"...

Comment: This is trivially true, since for two sufficiently cold stars at sufficiently high measured wavelength, the magnitude of both stars will be zero. The non-trivial case, which is a specific wavelength for two stars that is non-zero and the same for both is perhaps more interesting.

Comment: It can be formulated as how much their spectra depart from the black body one. And as for the previous comment, staying away from the tails..